# React null event handler testing with jest and enzyme

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

How to test null event handler in React Native with Jest and Enzyme? Branches test status %62.5 because i cant test null event handlers. I tried mock function but it's not working.

[image: coverage]
[image: code]
[image: test]

Comment: What happens if you don't pass in anything fo the param?

`const wrapper = shallow(<TextInput value="Test" />);`

Answer (score 0):

```
it('renders correctly text input with empty onBlur handler', () => {
  const mockFn = jest.fn();

  const wrapper = shallow(<TextInput value="Test" />);
  const textInput = wrapper?.find('[testID="textInput"]');
  textInput.simulate('blur');

  expect(mockFn).not.toBeCalled();
});
```

working with this at the moment branches is 100% but is this an effective test? Already mockFn function never be called.